# how to play a video on startup of the app or on viewdidload with done button?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have been able to successfully play a video on start of the app by calling a function that plays the video in the viewDidLoad method. But on doing so, i am unable to see the "Done" button. The "Done" button only seems to appear if i call that same function with the help of a button. I am posting the code below. How will I make this done appear by calling the same function in the viewDidLoad method? What have i been doing wrong? Thank you!

in my viewcontroller.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];

      [self playMedia];
}

- (void) playMedia {

        //hide status bar first
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
        //resets again in playMediaFinished

        movieFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sec" ofType:@"mp4"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: movieFile];

        moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playMediaFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];

        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

        CGAffineTransform transform = self.view.transform;

        [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];

        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

        NSLog(@"Should be playing Movie");

    }

- (void) playMediaFinished: (NSNotification*) theNotification {
       moviePlayer = [theNotification object];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];

        if ([moviePlayer
             respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
        {
            [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
            [playerView removeFromSuperview];
            //reset status bar
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
        }    
            NSLog(@"Should be DONE playing Movie");

    }
```

Comment: You can copy the code as is and just change the name of the mp4 file in order to test this code out. Help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You should add the "DONE" button as the subview to the movie player. Have you tried that?

Comment: Are you suggesting i hardcode a DONE button? I can try doing that.

Comment: I just understood what you meant by adding the DONE subview. I shall try that right now.

Comment: UPDATE : Didnt work :( Maybe you could show me how it's done?

Comment: I need to ask that question anyways so i will create a new question. And post a link here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this using `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`. I'm not surprised starting a video in `viewDidLoad` is causing unexpected behavior considering you're presenting the video before the main view appears on screen. Keep in mind, the view is done loading before it is actually visible.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i did try calling the method first in viewDidLoad then viewDidAppear, and they both seem to be doing the same thing. Which is, not showing the done button on the left corner like it normally would. Do you think this line of code has anything to do with it? [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];

Comment: The video does not show if i do not include the earlier line of code when the video method is called in the viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear method. But if i had my method tied into a button and pressed that button in the view, the video player loads normally, with done button and all.

Comment: By removing this line of code : [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)]; And keeping it simple, calling the method in the viewDidAppear made it work. I dont know what i was thinking. Thank you!

Comment: Doing this however shows the view first then plays the video, is there a way to go straight to showing the video?